# How to edit SharePoint online library JS files in visual studio code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, html-editor

I am having all my custom JS and Aspx files in custom SharePoint Library. How can I open the SharePoint library in visual studio code ?

I have tried with SPGO extension but this is also not working.

Can you please someone tell me how we can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise OneDrive for Business to access the files via file explorer (this would allow you to open them via Visual Studio Code).

However, SharePoint Online isn't designed to be used as a code repository. You would be better off using Azure DevOps or GitHub to store your code.

Comment: if we are editing aspx files from OneDrive, once the file is synced then aspx page is not opening in Browser. Instead the file is getting downloaded.

Comment: I would recommend using a Azure DevOps or GitHub for a code repository. SharePoint Online is not designed to be used as a code repository.

Comment: Got your point , but the project is already developed now i can't change it. Now I want to make one small change in the aspx file and i used SP Editor chrome extension. The changes are reflecting but file is not opening .Getting "Sorry, something went wrong
File Not Found." Error.

Comment: To open an ASPX file from a SharePoint site, you'll need to enable custom scripts. You can do this from the classic settings page in the SharePoint admin center. Worth noting that there are security implications of enabling this setting.

Comment: thanks for your comment.I don't have permission for admin center , anything we can do it from site collection level? or any other options are available ?

Comment: Sadly not, it's a tenant security setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script I suppose classic sites, allow you to create classic pages which are ASPX files but that's slightly different. I would recommend using communication sites with modern SharePoint pages, if you're looking to create a SharePoint intranet/information portal.